# ServletFilter Not Called on AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, guice, servlet-filters

I am using Guice to setup a filter to process all requests on AppEngine.  Guice setup is as follows:

```java
public void configureServlets() {
    filter("*").through(RedirectFilter.class);
}
```

The filter:

```java
@Singleton
public class RedirectFilter implements Filter {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RedirectFilter.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        URL url = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString());
        String domain = url.getHost();

        logger.info("host: " + domain + " path: " + url.getPath());

        if (!domain.startsWith("www")) {
            if (domain.startsWith("en")) {
                response.sendRedirect("http://www.mysite.com/en" + url.getPath());
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
    ...
}
```

However, the filter is not being called for any request.

Any ideas on why it might not be called?

**UPDATE:** The filter seems to be called with URLs such as http://en.mysite.com/xxx but not with http://en.mysite.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [AppEngine documentation on static files](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/staticfiles):

> There are many cases where you want to serve static files directly to
>   the web browser. Images, CSS stylesheets, JavaScript code, movies and
>   Flash animations are all typically served directly to the browser. For
>   efficiency, App Engine serves static files from separate servers than
>   those that invoke servlets.
>
> By default, App Engine makes all files in the WAR available as static
>   files except JSPs and files in WEB-INF/. Any request for a URL whose
>   path matches a static file serves the file directly to the
>   browser—even if the path also matches a servlet or filter mapping. You
>   can configure which files App Engine treats as static files using the
>   appengine-web.xml file.

More info on this topic [at this link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Static_files_and_resource_files).

To have your filter called when static HTML files are requested place the following in your `appengine-web.xml` file:

```
<static-files>
  <include path="/**.png" />
  <!-- other includes go here -->
  <exclude path="/**.html" />
</static-files>
```

More info on static file configuration for AppEngine at [this link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Including_and_excluding_files).